# Angular *ngIf check if key exists in map

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular-ng-if

I have a map that looks like:

```
let mapToSearch =
{
  'aaa': '123',
  'bbb': '456'
}
```

and I have a variable:

```
let keyToFind = 'aaa';
```

In my HTML template, in an Angular `*ngIf` block, I want to check if `keyToFind` matches any key within this map.

Something like JS `array.indexOf()`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mapToSearch.indexOf(keyToFind)">
  Hello world
</ng-container>
```

Is such a thing possible with maps within a template?

---

**Update (including Solution)**

Thanks for all your answers. All your answers are valid for working with a object literal (this was my mistake - I should have declared the map differently in the question).

However, for a ES6 map, I discovered I can use `map.has(key)` in the template.

Declare map with `map.set()`:

```
let mapToSearch = new Map();
mapToSearch.set('aaa', '123'};
mapToSearch.set('bbb', '456'};
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mapToSearch.has(keyToFind)">
  Hello World
</ng-container>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has

Comment: Yes, typically you would call a method inside the .ts file though

Comment: mapToSearch is really just an object, not a map btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful of the performance hit you take when supplying an expression and not a primitive to the *ngIf directive.  If you supply an expression or function then Angular's digest cycle will have to evaluate the expression every time.  To test, add a console.log() statement to a function inside ngIf - *ngIf="showMyElement()" - and watch how many times it gets called when you navigate around your application.

Melindu's answer is pretty good (for your case I would do this) - *ngIf="mapToSearch[keyToFind]"

A good habit to get into is to setup a boolean in your component and update that boolean anytime your collection/object changes.  Generally when you have more complex scenarios there aren't too many operations on the page that requires that boolean to be updated. So it's better to track those changes yourself in the component, than it is to let angular reevaluate an expression or function every digest.

**app.html**

```
<div *ngIf="keyIsFound"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
keyIsFound: boolean;
mapToSearch = {};

private checkKey(key: string) {
    this.keyIsFound = this.mapToSearch[keyToFind]
}
// Collection changes
addToMap(newKey: string, newValue: any) {
   this.mapToSearch[newKey] = newValue;
   checkKey(newKey);
}
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer - it wasn't quite what I needed but it put me on the right lines. Thanks Ryan!

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve if using following simple approach.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mapToSearch[keyToFind]">
  Hello world
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Please mark it if it's the correct answer. It may be helpful to others also

Comment: This fails if mapToSearch[keyToFind] = 0 or false

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a property is defined in `mapToSearch` with [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ejunw)):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mapToSearch.hasOwnProperty(keyToFind)">
  Hello world
</ng-container>
```

`hasOwnProperty` will return `true` if the property exists, even if the associated value is falsy. This is different from `mapToSearch[keyToFind]`, which will return `false` in the following cases:

```
prop: ""
prop: 0
```

Comment: How can I check directly from json file and I want to check both key and value in condition ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mapToSearch.aaa === '123'">
  Hello world
</ng-container>
```

if mapToSearch doesn't define aaa, then the result will be value undefined

Answer (score 0):

Since Your Data is Object You can Use keyvalue If you are using angular 6.1

```
<div *ngFor="let key of mapToSearch | keyvalue">
<ng-container *ngIf="key.key==keyToFind">
Hello world
</ng-container>
</div>
```

If your data is array then you can use method to return the data

**html**

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="KeyToFind(keyToFind)">
      Hello world
    </ng-container>
```

**ts**

```
KeyToFind(ktf){
 return this.mapToSearch.map(data=>data[ktf]; }).indexOf(ktf);
}
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo keyToFind needs to be changed to KeyToFind. Or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mapToSearch[keyToFind]"></ng-container>
```

Or, you can write a function in the component:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isKeySet(mapToSearch, keyToFind)"></ng-container>

public isKeySet(obj: any, key: string): boolean {
    return key in obj;
}
```

Or, you could write a pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mapToSearch | isKeySet:keyToFind)"></ng-container>

@Pipe({name: 'isKeySet'})
export class IsKeySetPipe implements PipeTransform {
     public transform(value: any, key?: string) {
         return key in value;
     }
}
```